# Linq to XML - multilevel

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm having a bit of an issue with a Linq to xml query.  Please see the data below.

```
<area id="16">
    <standard value="1">
      <temp value="M" />
    </standard>
    <standard value="2">
      <temp value="M" />
    </standard>
    <standard value="3">
      <temp value="M" />
    </standard>
  </area>

  <area id="17">
    <standard value="1">
      <temp value="M" />
    </standard>
    <standard value="2">
      <temp value="M" />
    </standard>
    <standard value="3">
      <temp value="M" />
    </standard>
  </area>
```

Basically, I want to extract the temp value from the xml when I have the area id and standard value as variables.

I can get the area by the following query

```
    IEnumerable<XElement> area =
        from c in areaRisk.Elements("area")
        where (string)c.Attribute("id") == ddlArea.SelectedValue.ToString()
        select c;
```

but I'm unsure how then to get the temp value using a similar query on the area XElement enumerable or if it's possible to modify the above query to extract the value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all in one query:

```
// change the assignment with whatever you want
int areaId = 17;
int standardValue = 3;
```

Syntax-based query solution:

```
string tempValue =
    (from c in areaRisk.Elements("area")
     where (int)c.Attribute("id") == areaId 
     from s in c.Elements("standard")
     where (int)s.Attribute("value") == standardValue 
     select (string)c.Element("temp").Attribute("value")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or method-based query:

```
string tempValue = areaRist.Elements("area")
                           .FirstOrDefault(a => (int)a.Attribute("id") == areaId)
                           .Elements("standard")
                           .FirstOrDefault(s => (int)s.Attribute("value") == standardValue)
                           .Element("temp")
                           .Attribute("value")
                           .Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, the syntax-based solution brings up a null reference error but changing c.Element("temp").Attribute("value")).FirstOrDefault(); to s.Element("temp") fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your area ID's are unique, change your query to return only the matching area like this:

```
XElement area =
    (from c in areaRisk.Elements("area")
    where (string)c.Attribute("id") == ddlArea.SelectedValue.ToString()
    select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then you can call another `Elements()` on it:

```
var result = area.Elements("standard").Select(s => new {
    ID = s.Attribute("id").Value,
    Temp = s.Element("temp").Attribute("value") 
});
```

Which will give you all temp ID's and values.